# JsHint - Hide This Message: ES5 option is now set per default

Tags: javascript, gulp, jshint

I'm using gulp-jshint, and the following error message is annoying:

```
ES5 option is now set per default
```

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's just telling you that it is the default so you don't need to add it as an option. Look in the .jshintrc file and remove `"es5": true`.

http://jslinterrors.com/es5-option-is-now-set-per-default

Comment: That's very obvious, but what if I want the es5 flag set to true for only one file, as in `/*jshint es5:true*/`?

Comment: Because it is the default, your comment would have no affect. First set the global es5 setting to false then you can add the inline comment per file.

Comment: Sure, but jshint throws the error at me when it reaches the comment, even though my global settings say `es5:false` :(

Comment: Also why does jshint fail with an error just because this setting is now the default? Could just log this as a hint and proceed.

Answer (score 5):

For me it was line:

```
 "esversion"     : 5,
```

in `.jshintrc`. When I commented it problem disappeared.

Comment: This fixed it. Using gulp-jshint 2.0.0.

Comment: Commenting out "esversion" also helped to clear "Incompatible values for the 'undefined' and 'undefined' linting options" errors.